# R: correctly reorder factor levels - avoid duplicated factor levels? {ggplot2}

Tags: r

The questions abut duplicated levels in factors resulting in:

```
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

has been addressed multiple times. However, I still can't figure out how to transform my data correctly, with aim to avoid the introduction of duplicated levels in my data?

I have a data frame, want to make a plot and change the order of levels in my plot. That where my duplicated levels are created, and I can't rewrite my `order` to not to introduce them. Please, **how to write my factors levels reordering correctly?**

```
df1<-data.frame(year = rep(2002:2005, 5),
                  rate  = sample(30,20),
                  gridcode = rep(1:2, each = 10),
                  distance = rep(c(100,200), 10))

# change order - !!! how to write this correctly?
df1$gridcode <- factor(df1$gridcode, 
                       levels=df1$gridcode[
                       order(df1$gridcode, decreasing = TRUE)])               


# plot values                 
ggplot(df1,aes(x = distance, 
                               y= rate, 
                               fill = as.factor(gridcode)))  +    
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")  +
  facet_grid(. ~ year)
```

Comment: You need to wrap a `unique` around your levels specification, otherwise you are assigning the levels heaps of times - `unique(df1$gridcode)[order(unique(df1$gridcode), decreasing = TRUE)]` for example.

Comment: thanks @thelatemail, seems to work! can you please post it as an answer, that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap a `unique` around your `levels=` specification, otherwise you are assigning the levels heaps of times:

```
unique(df1$gridcode)[order(unique(df1$gridcode), decreasing = TRUE)]
#[1] 2 1
```

vs.

```
df1$gridcode[order(df1$gridcode, decreasing = TRUE)]
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```